# How is Ubuntu pronounced?

Tags: 15.04

Is Ubuntu pronounced as **you-buntu** or **oo-buntu**?

Or both?

How does Mark Shuttleworth pronounce it?

Just been wondering...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pronounced **oo-boon-too**.

https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's pronounced as "oo-buntu".